# Disable JS chrome selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to disable js after run the driver ?
I don't want to add

```
    options.AddArguments("--disable-javascript");
```

because I just want to disable it on one page

Comment: I did a quick investigation and didn't find a clean answer.  Do you have access to edit the page you're trying to disable javascript on?  Since Javascript has global scope, you might be able to set a flag via selenium, as in click a 'disable Javascript' button and have your functions check for that flag before they perform their actions.  This way is a bit hokey and I would definitely make sure to have your build pipeline strip this out of your code before it gets near production, but it is one option.